# Starting a Background Instance of Matlab on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, bash, matlab, operating-system

In Windows you can use the following command in Matlab to start a new instance of MATLAB which will run in the background (i.e. you can keep executing commands in your first version of MATLAB).

> > system('matlab &')

An analogous call in OSX,

> > system([matlabroot '/bin/matlab &'])

however results in the display of the splash image, then nothing. If I take out the ampersand, the new instance opens as expected. Unfortunately, this won't work for me, I really need to be able to control the first instance of MATLAB while the second is running.

Does anyone know why this discrepancy between the operating systems exists? By the way, I'm using OSX 10.7, Windows 7 64 bit, and MATLAB R2012a on Mac and R2012b on PC.

As some background, I'm trying to write a generic tester for an interactive command line interface that uses the input() function extensively.

**Edit:** I should have mentioned that the command

/Applications/MATLAB_R2012a.app/bin/matlab &

works as expected from the OSX terminal. In other words, a new instance of MATLAB opens and new commands can be entered into the terminal. So this problem seems to be specific to the system() function in OSX matlab.

Also, I tried adding that command to a bash script and calling the script from matlab, but had the same problem that I did with putting the command into the system() function.

Thanks

Comment: There is the `-nosplash` command line option for `matlab.exe` - perhaps this is what you're looking for?

Comment: The problem isn't that the splash screen is displayed in Mac, it's that after the splash screen the second instance of MATLAB doesn't open.

Comment: Yes, but have you tried it with `-nosplash` and without the terminating `&`? I believe this will do what you want. I don't know why the `&` symbol is behaving differently on OSX.

Comment: I tried it with -nosplash on OSX with the ampersand, and as you would expect, nothing at all happens (no splash screen, no new instance of matlab). I tried it without the ampersand, and the new instance opens, but commands can't be executed by the first instance. This is unfortunately not acceptable.

Comment: Try it **without** the ampersand. This is, of course, assuming you want the command window to be displayed (which your question seems to indicate).

Comment: ... "I tried it without the ampersand, and the new instance opens, but commands can't be executed by the first instance.". That's a quotation from my last comment.

Comment: Ah sorry, didn't realise it prevented use of the first instance. You could create a shell script that opens the instance and call that with an ampersand.

Comment: No problem. I tried the shell script idea - it didn't work unfortunately, I'll put the details in an edit to the question.

Comment: Does the command with the ampersand work correctly from the Terminal when another instance of Matlab is already running? Can you use it to open two or three instances concurrently? What happens if you exit the terminal after launching the new Matlab process; does it stay up?

Answer (score 0):

This is a long shot, but it might be happening because when you invoke the new instance of Matlab from Matlab with the `system()` command on Unix or OS X, the `matlab_helper` process forks and runs a shell process to run the new application. If you omit the ampersand, the shell blocks and waits for the program to finish, and `system()` waits for it, so the first Matlab locks up. And (here's the speculation part) if you add the ampersand, Matlab launches in the background, and then the forked shell exits, which then causes the new Matlab process to exit because its parent process (the shell) has exited. (Windows doesn't have the same parent/child process relationships, process launch mechanism, or shells, which would explain the different behavior.)

You could try prefixing the command with `nohup`, which protects processes from getting killed by SIGHUP, which might be what's happening here to your second Matlab process.

```
system(['nohup ' matlabroot '/bin/matlab &'])
```

You could also try using the OS X `open` command to launch a new independent instance. Something like this. You may need to fiddle with the options and path, but `-n` should be what gives you a new instance. It should be pointing at `/Applications/MATLAB_R2012a.app`; I'm assuming that's what `matlabroot` is returning on OS X.

```
system(['open -na ' matlabroot])
```

You could also try running it from the Java process-launching features from within Matlab instead of with `system()`. `Runtime.exec()` doesn't block like `system()` does, and there may be other quirks to `system()`, like the `matlab_helper` architecture. Try launching it with `java.lang.Runtime` from Matlab.

```
jrt = java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime();
newMatlabProcess = jrt.exec([matlabroot '/bin/matlab']);
```

You can try the other command line variants above using this mechanism too, and you may need to redirect stdout to /dev/null, since the new processes input and output are buffered in to that `newMatlabProcess` object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use applescript to do this. I do something like this:

```
! osascript -e "tell application \"Terminal\" to do script \"cd `pwd`;matlab -nojvm -nosplash -r 'why'\""
```

This example opens a new Matlab instance, in the current directory, and runs the command "why". You can remove the "-nojvm" if you need java in your background Matlab process